# Is there xsd for the xml responses of the Prestashop webservices?

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to develop a java api for the prestashop webservices. 
I would like to use Jaxb and generate my pojo from xsd files but I cannot find them.

Someone know where I could get them?

Comment: From my understanding this is a REST service thus there are no WSDL's and there are no XSD files. See this link http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

Comment: Yeah sure there is no wsdl as it is a REST service but I thought the team may have xsd to validate their xml during test or whatever.
It would be interesting to have xsd also to validate the structure of the content before sending it.

Comment: So this REST service is using XML and not JSON? If this is the case you should contact the developers for xsd access. There is a emerging WSDL like file for REST services called WADL though I have not seen this in use too much.

Comment: Yes there are using XML. I will try to contact them. I hoped using the prestashop tag on stackoverflow would be enough.
Never heard of the WADL.
Thank you for your answers

Comment: You might find the following interesting http://blog.belvg.com/prestashop-web-services.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I already read it on the official website. They also have a scala and python api. 
Unfortunately the scala application is not compatible and I tried to compile it try modifying it with sbt and never succeed.
I would rally want to do my own in java as it will be integrated to a google app engine application in java.